# Flutter Image Picker Force User To Take Video NOT Picture

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin to select from camera or gallery. The main issue I'm trying to avoid is that the user can initially take a picture instead of recording a video. The second time they do it, the phone remembers the last selection and starts as video. How to I force video capture mode?

Simple Example:

```
ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

PickedFile file = await _picker.getVideo( //file should be a video, not a picture
    source: ImageSource.camera,  //how can I force this menu to "jump" to video capture mode
    maxDuration: const Duration(seconds: 60)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it appears to be only happening in the emulator. Real devices are defaulting to video, so for now this can be summed up as an emulator issue. Feel free to comment with any info :)